# How to partially apply case class with type parameter in Scala

Tags: scala, generics, partialfunction

So I have a tuple that I want to pass as the parameters for a case class in Scala. For case classes without type parameters, this is easy, as I can do:

```
 scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
 defined class Foo

 scala> (Foo.apply _)
 res0: (Int, Int) => Foo = <function2>

 scala> val tuple = (1, 2)
 tuple: (Int, Int) = (1,2)

 scala> res0.tupled(tuple)
 res1: Foo = Foo(1,2)

 scala> Foo.tupled(tuple)
 res2: Foo = Foo(1,2)
```

However, if the case class has a type parameter, it doesn't seem to work:

```
scala> (Bar.apply _)
res26: (Nothing, Nothing) => Bar[Nothing] = <function2>

scala> res26.tupled(tuple)
<console>:18: error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Int, Int)
 required: (Nothing, Nothing)
              res26.tupled(tuple)
                           ^
scala> (Bar[Int].apply _)
<console>:16: error: missing arguments for method apply in object Bar;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              (Bar[Int].apply _)

scala> Bar.tupled(tuple)
<console>:17: error: value tupled is not a member of object Bar
              Bar.tupled(tuple)
                  ^

scala> Bar[Int].tupled(tuple)
<console>:17: error: missing arguments for method apply in object Bar;
follow this method with `_' if you want to treat it as a partially applied function
              Bar[Int].tupled(tuple)
                 ^
```

How do I partially apply a case class with a type parameter? I'm using Scala 2.10.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This appears to work:

```
scala> case class Foo[X](a:X, b: X)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo.apply[Int] _
res1: (Int, Int) => Foo[Int] = <function2>

scala>
```

Comment: The only permutation I didn't try :p

Comment: The thing to realize is that `Foo` is an object, and objects can't have type parameters, only classes and functions can.

Comment: Wouldn't it be more accurate to say that only classes and methods can have type parameters? This is my understanding from reading some of the documentation behind Shapeless (http://www.chuusai.com/2012/04/27/shapeless-polymorphic-function-values-1/)

Comment: Yeah I'm being sloppy when I say "function" for "method".